# Getting terminal columns and rows in x86_64 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, x86-64

As the title suggests, is there a way of getting the columns and rows, as a  in x86_64 assembly?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, I am very new to x86_64 assembly (I started last night).

Comment: There's nothing special about asm for this.  If you're writing a program for Linux or other POSIX OS, you use the normal `ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, ...)` system call you'd use from C, same as `strace stty -a` shows.  Or check an environment variable, if you want to rely on that.  If you're writing an EFI bootloader, you'd use an EFI function.  If you're writing code for bare metal, it's up to you to set the video hardware to whatever mode you want.

Comment: So I should use `ioctl`, i'll look into it thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the size of a terminal with the [system call no. 16 (`sys_ioctl`)](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/). Its parameters are identical to the C function [`ioctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl). The relevant command is `TIOCGWINSZ`.

Let's get some informations with C:

```
// inspired by https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    struct winsize sz;

    printf("STDOUT_FILENO = %u\n", STDOUT_FILENO);
    printf("TIOCGWINSZ = 0x%X\n", TIOCGWINSZ);
    printf("SIZEOF sz (bytes): %lu\n", sizeof sz);

    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &sz);

    printf("Screen width: %u  Screen height: %u\n", sz.ws_col, sz.ws_row);
    return 0;
}
```

Call `sys_ioctl` with NASM:

```
; Name:     get_terminal_size.asm
; Assemble: nasm -felf64 get_terminal_size.asm
; Link:     ld -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -lc -o get_terminal_size get_terminal_size.o
; Run:      ./get_terminal_size

section .data
    fmt db `Screen width: %u  Screen height: %u\n`,0                ; backticks for '\n'

section .bss
    sz RESW 4

section .text
global _start
extern printf, exit

_start:

; http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/
; https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl

    mov eax, 16                 ; Kernel function SYS_IOCTL
    mov edi, 1                  ; STDOUT
    mov esi, 0x5413             ; TIOCGWINSZ
    mov edx, sz                 ; struct winsize sz
    syscall                     ; Call Linux

    mov rdi, fmt                ; string pointer
    movzx esi, WORD [sz+2]      ; sz.ws_col
    movzx edx, WORD [sz+0]      ; sz.ws_row
    xor eax, eax                ; no vector registers used
    call printf                 ; Call libc

    xor edi, edi                ; Exitcode 0 = exit(0)
    call exit                   ; Call libc
```

AT&T style:

```
# Name:     get_terminal_size.s
# Compile:  gcc -m64 -oget_terminal_size get_terminal_size.s
# Run:      ./get_terminal_size

.section .data
fmt:    .asciz "Screen width: %u  Screen height: %u\n"

.section .bss
.lcomm  sz, 8

.section .text
.globl main
main:

# http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/
# https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl

    mov $16, %eax           # Kernel function SYS_IOCTL
    mov $1, %edi            # STDOUT
    mov $0x5413, %esi       # TIOCGWINSZ
    mov $sz, %edx           # struct winsize sz
    syscall                 # Call Linux

    mov $fmt, %rdi          # string pointer
    movswl (sz+2), %esi     # sz.ws_col
    movswl (sz+0), %edx     # sz.ws_row
    xor %eax, %eax          # no vector registers used
    call printf             # Call libc

    xor %edi, %edi          # Exitcode 0 = exit(0)
    call exit               # Call libc
```

Comment: Note that this approach is not guaranteed to give results.  It should be used in conjunction to a lookup in the termcap database.